# Export ArangoDB values to bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, docker

I have a bash script that needs the count of records/documents that exist for a given arango collection. This seemed easy enough, I used the following `arangosh` call:

```
records=$(docker exec -it arango arangosh --javascript.execute scripts/getCount.js $collection --server.password '')
```

which then runs the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/arangosh --javascript.execute 

var collection = ARGUMENTS[0];
var doc = db[collection];

var c = doc.count();
print(c);
```

This appears to work, but when I `echo $records` I get the correct value but it appears bolded. This leads to other reading issues so I redirected the `docker exec` call to `cat -v` and got the following output:

`^[[1m#####^[[0m^M`

The #### is my record value and it is correct. How do I either properly print the value out of `arangosh` or out of `docker exec`? Or is the only path to strip these hidden ansi characters from my value?

**UPDATE:**

I was able to attempt `docker exec -it arango arangosh` and attempt the command `db._collection('my_collection').count()` directly. This returned a bolded value which I believe means that it contains the hidden characters (`arangosh` doesn't have `cat` defined so I couldn't verify 100%).

With that said I believe the question is, can this be exported in plain text or do I need to `sed` substitute these characters after my script receives the response?

Comment: I'm curious what happens if you omit the -t option

Comment: It looks like that works!

Comment: @Xtremefaith There was a similar question recently: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/487117/variable-containing-output-of-docker-exec-command-malaligned

Answer (score 0):

Still hoping for a better answer but I was able to get what I needed with the following:

```
imported=`docker exec -it arango arangosh --javascript.execute scripts/getRecords.js $collection --server.password '' | cat -v | sed 's/\(\^\[\[1m\)//g;s/\(\^\[\[0m^M\)//g'`
```

This simply passed the verbose output from docker to a `sed` substitution. Considering that for this script I expect the characters to be the same for all collections I am supplying to this script this should do the trick (just very limited).